# How to show that the following summation is true for matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices, summation, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I have following matrices $$\mathbf{b}\in R^n,~\mathbf{W}\in R^{n\times n},~ A\in R^{n\times m}.$$ Where $\mathbf{W}$ is a diagonal matrix and let us assume that the $i$-th row of $\mathbf{A}$ is written as $\mathbf{a}_i$ and the $i,i$-th entry of $\mathbf{W}$ is $w_i$. In this how to show that the following equality is true $$\mathbf{b^TWA(A^TWA)^{-1}A^TWb}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2b_i^2\mathbf{a}_i^T\left(\sum_{j=1}^nw_j\mathbf{a}_j\mathbf{a}_j^T\right)^{-1}\mathbf{a}_i$$ where $b_i$ is the $i$-th entry of $\mathbf{b}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I can show that the above statement is true if $\mathbf{A}$ is an identity matrix. But for general case I do not know. Further, I can show how the inverse part on the right is correct.

Comment: Right, I got the part in parentheses too.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz you mentioned that you got the answer. I will be very thankful to you please write the answer.

Comment: I would simplify by writing $U$ for a diagonal matrix which squares to $W$, then $X=UA$, $c=Ub$.  The LHS is then $c^T( X(X^T X)^{-1})X^{T})c$ which reminds me of pseudo-inverses.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you for your comment. But I cannot understand how to get the right hand side from your expression. Please add some details. Thank you.

Comment: It was a comment, I've not done it - no time today to get my head round pseudo-inverses.

Comment: Sorry, I got ahead of myself thinking I had solved it, but checked again and it wasn't a solution. I'm still checking, though.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz can you please upload the picture of your work? I may get some clue and make some progress towards getting a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't simply 
$$\mathbf b^T\mathbf W\mathbf A(\mathbf A^T\mathbf W\mathbf A)^{-1}\mathbf A^T\mathbf W\mathbf b =\mathbf b^T\mathbf W\mathbf A \mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf W^{-1}(\mathbf A^T)^{-1}\mathbf A^T\mathbf W\mathbf b=\mathbf b^T\mathbf W\mathbf b $$
?

Comment: But I did not say $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible

Comment: In fact I mentioned that $A$ can be non-square

Comment: I think your answer is incorrect and based on an erroneous assumption.